# What does the phrase “even a fool gets to be young once” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

In the movie *American Gangster*, Frank Lucas said

> Even a fool gets to be young once.

What does this phrase mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means that even though those who are older and wiser realize just how precious youth is, the gift of youth does not have to be earned.  Everyone gets to be young- even fools who don't appreciate it or spend it wisely.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you can let offenses committed by foolish young persons be excused due to a charitable attribution of their foolishness to their youth.  The expression is generally considered to be an act of graciousness, not entirely ascribing the foolishness to youth.

Answer (score -1):

It means you can be young forever if you understand the true spirit of life. Fools are young only once but the wise know the secret of youth.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

It means we're all held accountable for our wrongdoings and behaviors despite the fact we were taught it to be right or wrong. Its when we're taught the corrections and still go about solving minuet situations with the mentality of a fool who had never been taught.

Comment: You may find it usefull to join our sister-site [ell.se].